# Exponential inequality in complex

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, inequality

If $z_1,z_2 \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\textbf{Re}(z_1)$,$\textbf{Re}(z_1)\leq 0$ then $|e^{z_1}-e^{z_2}|\leq|z_1-z_2|$. Where $\textbf{Re}(z)$ is the real part.

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? You need to [provide context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) for your question. Otherwise it just looks like you want somebody to do your homework for you; that's not what this site is for. If you add some appropriate context, we will be happy to help.

Comment: Hint: consider the straight line joining $z_1,z_2$ and integrate $e^z$ on it, take absolute values and use the triangle inequality

Comment: yes, I get to what $|e^{z_1}-e^{z_2}|=\int_{[z_2,z_1]} e^z dz \leq ||e^{[z_2,z_1]}||_{\infty}\int_{0}^1 |z_1-z_2| dt= ||e^{[z_2,z_1]}||_{\infty}|z_1-z_2|$ but I do not know what to do after,

Comment: This has been asked and answered before: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/477505.